# Trying to enable/disable a textfield on checkbox click

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, checkbox, textfield

I'm trying to code a text field that is disabled when the check box is 'checked'.

Below is the code I'm using. I have no bloody idea why it's not working. I suspect it may be WordPress' fault but I'm new to Javascript so I'm hoping it's that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('input[name=AddressCheck]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#dbltext").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
       $("#dbltext").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }    

});
</script>



<input name="AddressCheck" type="checkbox" id="AddressCheck" /><br />
<input type="text" id="dbltext" disabled/>
```

Comment: So you are trying to Enable the text field when you check the checkbox? or the other way around?

Comment: When the page loads the text field should be disabled. Once the checkbox is 'checked', the text field should become enabled.

Comment: Ah! see the answers below. I don't think I understood your question at first time. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the script runs before the browser sees the rest of the page, so the element is never found, so nothing gets bound

try

```
$(document).ready(init);
// or document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
function init(){
    $('input[name=AddressCheck]').change(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $("#dbltext").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
      $("#dbltext").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }
    });
}
```

or move the script to the end of the body

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[name=AddressCheck]').click(function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) { 
            $("#dbltext").removeAttr('disabled');
        } 
});
```